# Why release build works differently than debug?

Tags: react-native

I built a new `APK` after I added `react-redux` and persist. The debug build is working perfect but the release one seems it didn't get the new code cause its working like before.

I'm not sure, why it's happening?. I tried `./gradlew` clean too but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` and then building the apk again

Answer (score 0):

Delete the build folder from the android/app directory. Delete Node Modules and do a fresh install. If this does not work then run metro bundler using the below command.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: weird, i dont have a build folder in android/app, but i have the debug and release folders there. The build folder is in android/build